# Insert Into SQL Syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to insert records into one table from another by using the following sql statement in VBA.  When I try to run it, VBA says there is a syntax error that I believe is in the parameters in the first line but I am unsure how to fix it. I am rather new to SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
"INSERT INTO Clients (Client ID)" & _
    "SELECT DISTINCT DD.[Client ID] " & _
    "FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
    "Where DD.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM " & tableName & " as DD)"
```

UPDATE: Full String:

```
INSERT INTO Clients (Client ID)SELECT DISTINCT DD.[Client ID] FROM FN_DataDump_ALL_11032014 as DD Where DD.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM  as DD)
```

Comment: generate the full string and post that in your question instead.

Comment: Why do you keep posting the same question?

Comment: Your 'tablename' is empty; you need a space after a ")" and you need [] around one 'Client ID'. And I agree that is VERY poor form to post the same question multiple times. Stay with one until it is fully resolved!

Comment: I guess you'll have to "quote" [Client ID] in the Insert clause as well. (like `insert into clients ([Client ID]) ...`). If your clients table has more mandatory columns than just client id, the system might regard your statement as syntactically incorrect independent of quoting issues

Answer (score 0):

If you could post error then it will be easy to understand.

However, I think that `Client ID` in the insert is recognized as not a one column name.

I suppose you could include it in  `[]` or ``` `` ```.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a space at the end of your first line.
"INSERT INTO Clients (Client ID)"
should be
"INSERT INTO Clients (Client ID) "